# How to add a new button on post

Tags: front-end, buttons

I would like to add a button next to the *edit button* on each article, with a link to a specific page.

This button is for translation purpose. It should redirect the user to the translation page of the post.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where do you want to add that ? in administration, on the page with the list of posts ?

Comment: I just learnt that the *edit link* I have come from my theme (Customizr), I thought itwas a Wordpress function. This link is on all post and pages, just above the title. I would like to add my link next to this one.

Comment: how are you intending to get the link to the translation page for the post? is that set in a custom field? the location of the `edit_post_link()` function, and/or the post title, depends on your theme. as it is, your question is too general to allow a precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the free theme Customizr, you can add content after the edit link with this code in the file `functions.php` of the child theme

```
add_action("__after_regular_heading_title", function () {

    $post = $GLOBALS["post"];

    ?>

        <span>
            an addition after the link to edit
            "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post->post_title);?>"
        </span>

    <?php

});
```